# Castelnuovo-Mumford Regularity of Product of Ideal Sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

> > **Proposition**. Suppose that $I$ and $J$ are ideals sheaves on $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ with regularities $m_{1}$ and $m_{2}$, respectively. Suppose also que the **zeros of $I$ and $J$ intersect in a set of dimension at most one**. Then $I \cdot J$ is $(m_{1} + m_{2})$-regular.

1) What does the bold part in the above proposition mean?

Since $I\cdot J$ is the image of $I \otimes J$ in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n}}$ we have the following exact sequence

$$0 \longrightarrow K \longrightarrow I \otimes J \longrightarrow I \cdot J \longrightarrow 0$$

Now, at this stage of the demonstration, it is stated that **the support of $K$ is contained in a set of dimension at most one**. Why?

$(2)$ This result is found in the following work: **On the Castelnuovo-Mumford Regularity Of Products of Ideal sheaves**- Jessica Sidman.

Any help is most welcome.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support of $K$ is contained in the intersections of the zeros of $I$ and $J$. Indeed if $p$ is not in the zeros of $J$ the sequence on the stalks becomes
$$
0 \longrightarrow K_p \longrightarrow I_p \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n,p} \longrightarrow I_p \longrightarrow 0
$$
and the multiplication map is an isomorphism. The same holds if $p$ is not a zero for $I$.

**ADDED:** Since we are taking a tensor product of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n,p}$-modules, we can write $$ I_p \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n,p} \ni \sum_j f_j \otimes g_j =\left(\sum_jf_jg_j \right)\otimes 1.$$
Hence every element of $I_p \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n,p}$ is given by $g\otimes 1$ for some $g\in I_p$. and the multiplication map sends $g\otimes 1$ to $g$ which is clearly an isomorphism.

Let me add an example where the multiplication map $I_p \otimes J_p \rightarrow I_p\cdot J_p$ is not an isomorphism. Let $p$ be the origin of $\mathbb{C}^3$ (with coordinates $(x,y,z)$) and let $$I_p= (x,y,z), \, J_p = (xz-y^2, y-z^2, x-yz).$$
Note that the element
$$
x\otimes (z^2-y) + y\otimes (x-yz) + z\otimes (y^2-xz) \in I_p\otimes J_p
$$
is in the kernel of the multiplication map.

Comment: First, thanks for your reply. Second, Taking the opportunity to learn, could you please explain why the multiplication map is an isomorphism?Again, thank you.

Comment: See if it helps

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much.